# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. (Django Tutorials)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I've been going through the Django 2 tutorials.

I got the following error:

```
#Error:
#django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
#django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern #name.
```

Did some googling and confirmed that I had named my view 'detail' and also had my app named.

Below are my codes.
Please tell what is wrong. I am following the tutorial by heart, but this came up. How can I fix it keeping in par with the tutorials? Thank you!

Files:
mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

mysite/polls/urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/
    # path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

mysite/polls/views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Additional:
mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: where is `views.detail`?

Comment: def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

Comment: My whole polls/views.py file : https://pastebin.com/su1kXEH4

Comment: Please suggest @gahan

Comment: My settings.py file: https://pastebin.com/gxq5Hacq

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xhdadmjA here's my index.html file

Comment: updated my answer after looking at your index.html file. this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined any function named as 'detail' in views.py file.

Add this code.

```
def detail(request, id):
    context = dict()
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

You have to add results and vote function as well.

Remove the commented lines from your index.html file. Syntax in these lines is not right and Django tries to parse commented lines as well before rendering.

Comment: I did add details function. here's my complete views.py file : https://pastebin.com/afc12wv3

Comment: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 1):

Remove from `mysite/urls.py` the `namespace` as you already specified app's `app_name`

or you can just remove the `app_name` and keep the `namespace` (not sure if this works in Django 2.0 as there are [some tweaks in app_name and namespace in this version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)).